# How to move contents of one element in a map to another element in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am trying to transfer/copy an element in a map, to another element in the map in Scala. For example:

```
Map(0 -> 5)
```

Let's say this is the initial state of the map. What I want to happen is the following:

```
Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 5)
```

So after the change has happened, 0 that initially points to 5, but after the transformation 0 will point to 0, and a new element is added (1) that points to 5.

I have tried the following:

```
theMap + (pointer -> (theMap(pointer) + 1))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 1
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What should happen if the **Map** has many elements? Do you want to transfer all elements or one in concrete? Will the transfer will always be the `key + 1`?

Comment: Hello, I should have mentioned, but "pointer" will be referring to an element in the map, in the example above, it has the value of the key '0'. Because we access maps via a key, so whatever number "pointer'" is, is the value that we are changing.

Comment: Is pointer also an input of the function? We only need to move pointer or any other element? will the keys always be ints, will the values always be ints? will the new element will always be the `pointer + 1`, will the pointer should be mapped to `0`? What should happen if the `pointer + 1` already exists?

Comment: So the key and the value will always be ints, and the source of "pointer" doesn't really matter, that is just a random number of keys that already exist. And ```pointer + 1``` is a new element every time.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
def transfer(pointer: Int)(map: Map[Int, Int]): Map[Int, Int] =
  map.get(key = pointer)  match {
    case Some(value) =>
      map ++ Map(
        pointer -> 0,
        (pointer + 1) -> value
      )

    case None =>
      // Pointer didn't exist, what should happen here?
      map // For now returning the map unmodified.
  }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
transfer(pointer = 0)(map = Map(0 -> 5))
// res: Map[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 5)
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in my implementation. What the program does is interprets Brainfuck, and I am not sure if you know about this language, but the functions '+' and '-' are what I am trying to implement.

Comment: @LondonMassive Sorry, I do not understand your comment, what does **Brainfuck** have to do with **Scala**, you didn't say that you were implementing the `+` method on a map? That method already exists, are you creating your own map?

Comment: Ok, so the program I am creating is a Brainfuck interpreter using Scala. And when a character is read from a Brainfuck file it corresponds to a command, and the '+' and '-' commands make changes to a map. I am having troubles with these.

Comment: @LondonMassive That has nothing to do with your question and I would suggest you open a new one explaining that in detail.